# Screen Colors Wrong on Android 3.2 Tablet

Tags: android, colors

I have an app that works very well under API-8 on real devices and on the emulator. I've installed it on two 3.2 tablets, and the screen colors have changed: The background color #66cc1111 (burgundy) shows as black, and objects with color #FFFFFFFF (white) shows as bright green.

Are there compatibility problems going from API-8 to API-14 that would explain this?
Have they changed the method to set the color of objects?

Comment: where are you using this color? I mean how, in xml file? in code? could you please post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had an old copy of a drawable xml file in the drawable-xhdpi folder that used a default color set. The other three drawable folders had the update file xml with the proper colors. Simple solution... and I'll never forget to copy a drawable over to all four folders again!